# Where is the headless chrome browser in a Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, pyppeteer

I am looking for the location of an executable in an Google App Engine (standard environment).

The reason is that I am trying to use pyppeteer for some work but pyppeteer always downloads chromium into a custom folder and then exits.

I saw that puppeteer works on GAE and I hope therefore that I can convince pyppeteer to run as well.

Here are the Google App Engine logs:

````
2019-07-23 17:39:33 default[test]  [W:pyppeteer.chromium_downloader] start chromium download.
2019-07-23 17:39:33 default[test]  Download may take a few minutes.
2019-07-23 17:39:33 default[test]
2019-07-23 17:39:34 default[test]    0%|          | 0/106826418 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:34 default[test]    2%|▏         | 1925120/106826418 [00:00<00:07, 13602613.39it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:34 default[test]    4%|▍         | 4392960/106826418 [00:00<00:06, 15716861.03it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:34 default[test]    6%|▌         | 6256640/106826418 [00:00<00:06, 16489218.92it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:34 default[test]    8%|▊         | 8407040/106826418 [00:00<00:05, 17728112.85it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:34 default[test]   11%|█         | 11683840/106826418 [00:00<00:04, 20557603.00it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:34 default[test]   13%|█▎        | 14356480/106826418 [00:00<00:04, 22086461.51it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:34 default[test]   16%|█▌        | 17008640/106826418 [00:00<00:03, 23246105.82it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:34 default[test]   18%|█▊        | 19374080/106826418 [00:00<00:03, 23225442.25it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:35 default[test]   20%|██        | 21729280/106826418 [00:00<00:03, 23203081.94it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:35 default[test]   24%|██▍       | 25681920/106826418 [00:01<00:03, 26483368.08it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:35 default[test]   27%|██▋       | 28508160/106826418 [00:01<00:02, 26759076.64it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:35 default[test]   29%|██▉       | 31313920/106826418 [00:01<00:02, 26995282.49it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:35 default[test]   32%|███▏      | 34375680/106826418 [00:01<00:02, 27987817.70it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:35 default[test]   35%|███▍      | 37253120/106826418 [00:01<00:02, 28005026.46it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:35 default[test]   38%|███▊      | 40212480/106826418 [00:01<00:02, 28458335.10it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:35 default[test]   40%|████      | 43100160/106826418 [00:01<00:02, 28379615.37it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:35 default[test]   43%|████▎     | 45967360/106826418 [00:01<00:02, 22218027.73it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:36 default[test]   45%|████▌     | 48414720/106826418 [00:01<00:02, 22336538.22it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:36 default[test]   48%|████▊     | 51435520/106826418 [00:02<00:02, 24224996.22it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:36 default[test]   51%|█████▏    | 54763520/106826418 [00:02<00:01, 26376309.32it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:36 default[test]   54%|█████▍    | 57569280/106826418 [00:02<00:02, 21505161.66it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:36 default[test]   56%|█████▌    | 60078080/106826418 [00:02<00:02, 22466550.18it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:36 default[test]   59%|█████▉    | 63027200/106826418 [00:02<00:01, 24192591.42it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:36 default[test]   61%|██████▏   | 65628160/106826418 [00:02<00:01, 24070010.24it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:36 default[test]   64%|██████▍   | 68556800/106826418 [00:02<00:01, 25428249.96it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:36 default[test]   68%|██████▊   | 72529920/106826418 [00:02<00:01, 28506739.68it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:37 default[test]   71%|███████   | 75581440/106826418 [00:02<00:01, 28986836.20it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:37 default[test]   74%|███████▎  | 78622720/106826418 [00:03<00:00, 29210576.39it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:37 default[test]   76%|███████▋  | 81643520/106826418 [00:03<00:01, 22926790.84it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:37 default[test]   79%|███████▉  | 84224000/106826418 [00:03<00:00, 23612840.24it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:37 default[test]   82%|████████▏ | 87193600/106826418 [00:03<00:00, 25157952.55it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:37 default[test]   84%|████████▍ | 89937920/106826418 [00:03<00:00, 25797481.66it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:37 default[test]   87%|████████▋ | 92672000/106826418 [00:03<00:00, 26235841.07it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:37 default[test]   89%|████████▉ | 95488000/106826418 [00:03<00:00, 26776710.45it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:37 default[test]   92%|█████████▏| 98232320/106826418 [00:03<00:00, 26824171.60it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:38 default[test]   95%|█████████▍| 100966400/106826418 [00:03<00:00, 26803548.31it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:38 default[test]   97%|█████████▋| 103925760/106826418 [00:04<00:00, 27583062.30it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:38 default[test]  100%|██████████| 106826418/106826418 [00:04<00:00, 25706775.94it/s]
2019-07-23 17:39:38 default[test]  [W:pyppeteer.chromium_downloader]
2019-07-23 17:39:38 default[test]  chromium download done.
2019-07-23 17:39:44 default[test]  [W:pyppeteer.chromium_downloader] chromium extracted to: /root/.local/share/pyppeteer/local-chromium/575458
2019-07-23 17:39:46 default[test]  [I:pyppeteer.launcher] Browser listening on: ws://127.0.0.1:22168/devtools/browser/c820f895-a90a-4242-a3fa-35dfda06be3f
2019-07-23 17:39:48 default[test]  [2019-07-23 17:39:48 +0000] [9] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2019-07-23 17:39:48 default[test]  [2019-07-23 17:39:48 +0000] [17] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 17)```
````

Answer (score 2):

Pyppeteer is downloading the chromium executable to the local filesystem which is not writeable [1], that is why when it tries to access the file, it is no longer there and it exits. You could download chromium to a storage bucket on Google Cloud Storage and then read the file from there.

> [1] [Reading and Writing Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/)
>
> In App Engine, the local filesystem that your application is deployed to is not writeable. This behavior ensures the security and scalability of your application.
>
> However, if the application needs to write and read files at runtime, App Engine provides a built-in Google Cloud Storage stream wrapper that allows you to use many of the standard PHP filesystem functions to read and write files in an App Engine PHP app.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try if I can't find the existing executable on app engine. I think it would be less error prone to use the one that's already there.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually run Pyppeteer on Google App Engine Flex. You just need to define a Dockerfile and point to the image container gcr.io/google_appengine/python which is GCR's standard Python image.

Then you'll want to add all the linux libraries that allows Chromium to run.

Here is the docker file:

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/python
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install  gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget

RUN virtualenv /env
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

RUN mkdir /your/app/path
ADD . /your/app/path
WORKDIR /your/app/path
ADD requirements.txt /your/app/path/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /your/app/path/requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-b", ":8080", "main:app"]
```

Then in your python file set the flag

```
args = ['--no-sandbox']
browser = await launch(args=args)
page = await browser.newPage()
```

So Chromium can run as root.

You can check out my full walk through and explanation [here](https://medium.com/@paulpierre/how-to-run-pyppeteer-on-google-app-engine-flex-or-how-i-lost-it-trying-701b09fadf99):